# Launch Watch App into middle view

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Basically, my app is laid out in the page format and I would like it to launch into the middle of the three pages. There is no way of setting a previous page segue, so I have been trying to do it in code.

I have the main view set to the first view, and I have tried a variety of methods to segue to the middle view as soon as the app is launched.

Here is the two ways I tried:

```
    if segueCheck == true {
        self.pushControllerWithName("budget", context: self)
        self.presentControllerWithName("budget", context: self)
        segueCheck = false
    }
```

The first presents the view, but as a completely separate view, and the second replaces the first view with the middle view.

Does anyone know how I can launch into the middle view and allow the user to swipe left and right of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WKInterfaceController`'s [`becomeCurrentPage()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/becomeCurrentPage) should be what you're looking for.

Let's create a new class for the center view controller, `CenterPageViewController`, and change its  `initWithContext:` method as follows

```
import WatchKit

class CenterPageViewController: WKInterfaceController {

    override init(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.init(context: context)

        super.becomeCurrentPage()        
    }
}
```

Now let's set the Custom Class for the middle page in your storyboard to `CenterPageViewController`

[image]

and finally hit run.

You won't be able to get rid of the initial transition from the left page to the center page, but the app will finally begin on the middle page.

Comment: Is there still no way to do it without animation?

Answer (score 1):

**Update Swift 3.0**

```
class CenterPageViewController: WKInterfaceController {

override init (){
    super.init()
    super.becomeCurrentPage()
  }
}
```

This will works...!!!

Thanks

Comment: You would want to move this into `awake(withContext context: Any?)`.

Comment: What about removing the animation from the first to 2nd page? Apple's Workout app behaves exactly this way, but without the animation.

Answer (score 1):

The new way to do this in watchOS 4 and higher is:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: 
["Controller1" "Controller2", "Controller3"], 
 contexts: [context1, context2, context3],
 orientation: WKPageOrientation.horizontal,
 pageIndex: 1)
```

Now you don't get the annoying animation when using `becomeCurrentPage()` when you want to start with the middle page.

Comment: Do you also have to add this code to `Controller1` and `Controller3`   with the correct  pageIndex (0,2 respectively)? Or is it sufficient to just add it to the  `Controller2 ` with page index of 1?

Comment: I add it wherever I need it in the app. It's like on iOS where you push a view onto the UINavigationController, except in this case you can kind of set multiple pages of controllers and decide which one to show. Then when you swipe to the right, or left, your two other controllers will display.