# apple watch application arrangement view of a next-page mode, how to jump the specified view?

Tags: ios, watchkit

apple watch application arrangement 7 with next-page view mode, were named: one, two ..... serven.
I like how to write code to make the program jump according to week view.
I'll get a week, how kind jump view?
O (∩_∩) O Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You mean page-based view?

For example, If you want to jump to second view, call `becomeCurrentPage()` in second WKInterfaceController.

ref. 
[Launch Watch App into middle view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097022/launch-watch-app-into-middle-view)